# I keep getting an Unknown column 'Andy' in 'where clause' error

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have looked this problem and yet still cant find the error in the code.  I used Dreamweaver's automated features to do this so I don't understand why I am getting an error at all.

My code on my login.php page is:

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
$_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['first'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['first'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "index.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "login.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_myStoreConn, $myStoreConn);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT `first`, password FROM `admin` WHERE `first`=%s AND     

password=%s",
 GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "-1"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

 $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $myStoreConn) or die(mysql_error());
 $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
 if ($loginFoundUser) {
 $loginStrGroup = "";

//declare two session variables and assign them
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
}
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
}
else {
header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
}
}
```

The code on the index.php page is:

```
 $colname_admin = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_admin = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_myStoreConn, $myStoreConn);
$query_admin = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `first` = %s",             

GetSQLValueString($colname_admin, "text"));
$admin = mysql_query($query_admin, $myStoreConn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_admin = mysql_fetch_assoc($admin);
$totalRows_admin = mysql_num_rows($admin);
```

Can anyone help so I don't take a shotgun to my iMac?!?!

Comment: I think you still need to quote it `SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `first` ='%s'

Comment: meda, Isn't it already quoted?

Comment: you are just formatting a string , if you need quotes then add it

Comment: BenEgan1991, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: do you get the errors when you add the quotes?

Comment: meda, im sorry im looking and i can't see where the quotes are missing from.  am i reading it wrong or is it not:

Comment: $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT 'first', password FROM   `admin` WHERE `first`=%s AND password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "-1"),  GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));

Comment: `$LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT 'first', password FROM  admin WHERE first='%s' AND password='%s'", GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "-1"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Atg10676*''' at line 1

Comment: get rid of sprint : `$LoginRS__query="SELECT 'first', password FROM  admin WHERE first = '$loginUsername' AND password='$password'";`

Comment: Meda, the whole page disappeared on me lol

Comment: I am sure you are not that new to php, please copy paste my comment exactly and replace your sprint code

Comment: meda, i did copy and paste.  when i put it on the server and ran login.php the page didnt show the content that i had before.

Comment: I posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23463610/1880431)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line from:

```
$LoginRS__query = sprintf("SELECT `first`, password FROM `admin` WHERE `first`=%s AND password=%s", GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "-1"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));
```

to the following:

```
$LoginRS__query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `first`=%s AND password=%s", GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "-1"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need single quotes around the comparison value in the `where` clause:

```
$query_admin = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `first` = '%s'", 
--------------------------------------------------------------^--^            
                       GetSQLValueString($colname_admin, "text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first get this to work then you can expand on this code

```
    $conn = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

    if (!$conn) {
        die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('mysql_db', $conn);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use database : ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $username=$_POST['first'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $query="";

    $query = sprintf("SELECT `first`, `password` 
                      FROM  admin 
                      WHERE first = '%s' AND password='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($username),
    mysql_real_escape_string($password));

    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);

    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 1) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
}
```